# How can I hide or show rows automatically based on a value in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My data looks like this;

```
       A           B
1 Project A    02/03/2014
2 Project B    03/05/2013
```

I want to automatically hide the rows with specific dates. I can have a cell outside of the range of actual data, where I can enter my desired year which if a date in a cell matches will hide the entire row(s) or will only show that particular row.

How do I do this without using VBA or macro?

Comment: You can't do this without VBA

Comment: Duplicate of [Show or hide rows in an Excel sheet subject to the value of a particular cell](http://superuser.com/q/726865/150988).

Comment: You can use conditional formatting to automatically highlight rows. It's not hiding the other data, but it will pick out the matches and doesn't need VBA.

Comment: @Scott, not a duplicate as the OP wants a non-VBA solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional formatting to set the foreground and background colours the same except for the rows you want. Not really the best if you have lots of rows.

You could use conditional formatting to set a colour in the required row cells and then set a colour filter (requires Excel 2013 I think). The problem with this is that you have to manually release and reset the filter if the conditionals change.

If you are open to a plugin, you could use the Microsoft PowerQuery plugin to query your sheet. This produces a 2nd sheet with just the data you want. You still need to refresh the query if the condition changes.