# VBA to hide certain rows based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, hide

I have some information in rows 9 to 38. I need to hide these rows based on a cell value, for example A8:

- If `A8=3` then only show rows 9 to 11 out of 38
- if `A8=9` then only show rows 9 to 18 out of 38
- If `A8=0` then hide all rows from 9 to 38.

... and so on, only for rows 9 to 38.

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim var As Variant

    'Determine if change was made to cell A8
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A8")) Is Nothing Then

        'Get value
        var = Range("A8").Value
        var = var + 9
        Debug.Print var

        'Hide all rows
        Rows("9:38").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        For i = 9 To var
        'Show Rows
        Rows("9:i").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Debug.Print i
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [Check this link,, help U to fix the issue](https://superuser.com/questions/728700/how-can-i-hide-or-show-rows-automatically-based-on-a-value-in-a-cell?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop is not needed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim var As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A8")) Is Nothing Then

        var = Range("A8").Value + 8

        Rows("9:38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If var > 8 Then
            Rows("9:" & var).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

For 2 blocks:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim var As Long
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A8")) Is Nothing Then

        var = Range("A8").Value + 8

        Rows("9:38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If var > 8 Then
            Rows("9:" & var).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A39")) Is Nothing Then

        var = Range("A39").Value + 39

        Rows("40:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If var > 39 Then
            Rows("40:" & var).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How would i include the same code for another cell? like multiple worksheet changes: for example 9:38 first section based on A8 and 41:47 based on A40

Comment: @JavyColón  You could put another big `IF()` block under the first.......................say   **A39** controlling the next set of rows.

Comment: i tried, but its not doing anything, only for the first A38

Comment: @JavyColón  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Found my mistake, Thank you very much!!!